# equals method doesn't work

Tags: java, equals

I'm practicing a simple `Java` GUI by making a login system without a database, but my if statement using `.equals` doesn't work because it always says incorrect password.

`contains()` work but I think it's not that secure

```
String user = USERNAME.getText();   
String pass = PASSWORD.getText(); 
if(user.equals("username") && pass.equals("password") ){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to GUI");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Username and password");    
}
```

Comment: `equals` is case sensitive, are you sure you're entering the correct values?  Perhaps add `System.out.println("[" + user + "]/[" + pass + "]");` to verify the values

Comment: Also, make sure you don't have blankspaces or anything like that. Always trim.

Comment: user and pass are lower csae? and no white spaces ?

Comment: `trim` might help you out.

Comment: Have you checked the content String variable pass.

Comment: When comparing credentials, I'd avoid `trim` as it produces an unrealistic comparison, but since you're just playing around ...

Comment: put a breakpoint at `if(user.equals("us...`, see what you have in `user` and `pass`

Comment: Please add exactly what you are typing in, and add a print method like suggested by @MadProgrammer.  Without more detail, it is impossible to determine where your problem is.

Comment: You should also reverse your string comparisons to avoid NullPointerExceptions - e.g. "username".equals(user)

Comment: USERNAME is a text field? If yes I am sure it already contains a space and you must be using an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

As @MadProgrammer pointed out that [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) is a case sensitive method.

```
"password1" is NOT EQUAL to "PASSWORD1" //The strings should match with case.
```

Also to avoid [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) a better way is

```
String user = USERNAME.getText();   
String pass = PASSWORD.getText();
if ("username".equals(user) && "password".equals(pass)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to GUI");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Username and password");
}
```

Comment: yes @MadProgrammer, I have entered the correct username and password but it still takes me to the else statement